# References formating

Tags: bibtex

I am looking for this specific format of references.
I edited numeric to some extent but it still does not look the same.
If you know what format this is, would you, please, also provide example code how to link the `.bib` and `.tex` files?

[image]

Comment: If you already "edited numeric", why don't you share your code with us and point out which elements need to be changed?

Comment: It could be the stylenames `acm ` or `siam` [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles) you can find different Bibtex bibliography styles. Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us/you and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)). Reproducing  and answering will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` ... `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Do you want to write up an answer, so we can mark this question as solved.

Comment: @moewe Done. I also changed the question tag to bibtex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with `pdflatex`,`bibtex`,2x`pdflatex` you will get the following solution with `acm`: **\bibliographystyle{acm}**

[image]

or with `siam`:  **\bibliographystyle{siam}**

[image]

**MWEB:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
@article{cite1,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {{Title One}},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year = {2005},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--42},
}
@book{cite2,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {{A Way More Important Title}},
  publisher = {Oxford},
  year = {2009},
  address = {New York}
}   
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Blablabla says: It is a test ~\cite{Nobody06} or \cite{cite1}.
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{siam}%{acm}
\end{document}
```